# Skip other If conditions

Tags: programming, random, conditional

I'm trying to write a code to "random" move in a matrix but it can't go to a certain position if it has a certain value (in this case I'm using the number 2). How do I make it to skip all other If conditions if one of them is found True? Another thing, is it possible to store the RandomChoise in a variable to be used later? Thank you

```
If[And[matrix[[i+1,j]]!=2,matrix[[i-1,j]]!=2,matrix[[i,j+1]]!=2,matrix[[i,j-1]]!=2], RandomChoice[{up,down,right,left}]]

If[And[matrix[[i+1,j]]!=2,matrix[[i-1,j]]!=2,matrix[[i,j+1]]=2,matrix[[i,j-1]]!=2], RandomChoice[{up,down,left}]]

If[And[matrix[[i+1,j]]!=2,matrix[[i-1,j]]!=2,matrix[[i,j+1]]!=2,matrix[[i,j-1]]=2], RandomChoice[{up,down,right}]]

If[And[matrix[[i+1,j]]!=2,matrix[[i-1,j]]=2,matrix[[i,j+1]]!=2,matrix[[i,j-1]]!=2], RandomChoice[{down,right,left}]]

If[And[matrix[[i+1,j]]=2,matrix[[i-1,j]]!=2,matrix[[i,j+1]]!=2,matrix[[i,j-1]]!=2], RandomChoice[{up,right,left}]]

If[And[matrix[[i+1,j]]=2,matrix[[i-1,j]]=2,matrix[[i,j+1]]!=2,matrix[[i,j-1]]!=2], RandomChoice[{right,left}]]

If[And[matrix[[i+1,j]]!=2,matrix[[i-1,j]]=2,matrix[[i,j+1]]!=2,matrix[[i,j-1]]=2], RandomChoice[{down,right}]]

If[And[matrix[[i+1,j]]!=2,matrix[[i-1,j]]=2,matrix[[i,j+1]]=2,matrix[[i,j-1]]!=2], RandomChoice[{down,left}]]

If[And[matrix[[i+1,j]]=2,matrix[[i-1,j]]!=2,matrix[[i,j+1]]!=2,matrix[[i,j-1]]=2], RandomChoice[{up,right}]]

If[And[matrix[[i+1,j]]=2,matrix[[i-1,j]]!=2,matrix[[i,j+1]]=2,matrix[[i,j-1]]!=2], RandomChoice[{up,left}]]

If[And[matrix[[i+1,j]]!=2,matrix[[i-1,j]]!=2,matrix[[i,j+1]]=2,matrix[[i,j-1]]=2], RandomChoice[{up,down}]]

If[And[matrix[[i+1,j]]=2,matrix[[i-1,j]]=2,matrix[[i,j+1]]!=2,matrix[[i,j-1]]=2], RandomChoice[{right}]]

If[And[matrix[[i+1,j]]=2,matrix[[i-1,j]]=2,matrix[[i,j+1]]=2,matrix[[i,j-1]]!=2], RandomChoice[{left}]]

If[And[matrix[[i+1,j]]!=2,matrix[[i-1,j]]=2,matrix[[i,j+1]]=2,matrix[[i,j-1]]=2], RandomChoice[{down}]]

If[And[matrix[[i+1,j]]=2,matrix[[i-1,j]]!=2,matrix[[i,j+1]]=2,matrix[[i,j-1]]=2], RandomChoice[{up}]]
```

Comment: Check out `Which`...

Comment: And also remember that `=` is `Set` and `==` is `Equal` used for comparison purposes.

Answer (score 7):

This is more than you've asked but tell me if this works for you. I've added artificial border with `2s` around the world :)

```
init[] := (dim = {10, 10};
  world = ArrayPad[RandomInteger[{1, 10}, dim], {1, 1}, 2];
  known = ArrayPad[ConstantArray[0, dim], {1, 1}, 2];
  p = {2, 2};
  (known[[##]] = world[[##]]) & @@ p;)

init[]
MatrixForm /@ {world, known}
```

> [image]

```
    While[
     True,     
     Composition[
      p = #[[1]]; (known[[##]] = world[[##]]) & @@ p; 
      If[#[[2]] == 10, Break[]]; &,
      If[# === {}, Break[], RandomChoice[#]] &,
      DeleteCases[#, {_, 2}] &,
      Thread[{#, Extract[world, #]}] &
     ][
       # + p & /@ {{1, 0}, {0, 1}, {-1, 0}, {0, -1}}
      ]
     ]
```

> [image]

---

#### Dynamic fun:

```
init[];
Dynamic@MatrixForm@known

While[
 True,     
 Composition[
   p = #[[1]]; (known[[##]] = Style[world[[##]], Bold, 15, Red]) & @@ p; 
     Pause@.1;  If[#[[2]] == 10, Break[]]; &,
   If[# === {}, Break[], RandomChoice[#]] &,
   DeleteCases[#, {_, 2}] &,
   (known[[##]] = Style[world[[##]], Bold, 15]) & @@ p; 
   Thread[{#, Extract[world, #]}] &
   ][
  # + p & /@ {{1, 0}, {0, 1}, {-1, 0}, {0, -1}}
  ]]
```

> [image]

Comment: Kuba's answer very much reminded me of Christian Jacob's works about Evolutionary Algorithms. Some fascinating Mathematica examples examples can be downloaded here: http://pages.cpsc.ucalgary.ca/~jacob/Evolvica/Downloading.html#TableOfContents

Comment: @AndréF. The `DeleteCases` part is responsible for dropping walls. The direction is chosen from the remaining parts. You must skip this part and include your code then.

Comment: @AndréF. Try this `Composition[
 
 With[{val = #[[2]], pos = #[[1]]},
   (known[[##]] = world[[##]]) & @@ pos;
   Switch[val, 10, p = pos; Break[], 2, {}, _, p = pos]] &,
 RandomChoice,
 Thread[{#, Extract[world, #]}] &
 ]`. Materials about what? :)

Comment: @AndréF. I find those [tutorials](http://www.wolfram.com/learningcenter/tutorialcollection/index.html) helpful. Choose one you want to focus at the moment and parse it.

Comment: I don't got exactly where I should change this part
`Composition[
 With[{val = #[[2]], pos = #[[1]]}, (known[[##]] = world[[##]]) & @@ 
    pos; Switch[val, 10, p = pos; Break[], 2, {}, _, 
    p = pos]] &, RandomChoice, Thread[{#, Extract[world, #]}] &]`
Should I change the previous `Composition` for this or just some part of it? @Kuba

Comment: @AndréF. Switch those two compositions ;) Please delete old not relevant comments.

Comment: Its still not exactly how I need it to work.
It needs to random select directions in `Known` and when it move update its value with the `world` value. If there is a wall in the `world` it must be updated to the `known` and than it should be excluded from the random selection when it start again. @Kuba

Comment: @AndréF. create additional list where you will store visited `2s` and then take a complement of possible directions with this set before you choose each time.

Comment: @Kuba Aren't those already visited `2s` stored in the `known`? How can I make the `DeleteCases` work only for the `2s` in `known` and not `world`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14993/discussion-between-andre-f-and-kuba).

Answer (score 5):

I like `Pick` for this:

```
Pick[
  {up, down, left, right},
  Extract[matrix, {{i + 1, j}, {i - 1, j}, {i, j - 1}, {i, j + 1}}],
  x_ /; x != 2
 ] // RandomChoice
```

Answer (score 4):

```
a = matrix[[i + 1, j]];
b = matrix[[i - 1, j]];
c = matrix[[i, j + 1]];
d = matrix[[i, j - 1]];

Which[
 And[a != 2, b != 2, c != 2, d != 2], RandomChoice[{up, down, right, left}],
 And[a != 2, b != 2, c == 2, d != 2], RandomChoice[{up, down, left}],
 (* ... *)
 And[a == 2, b != 2, c == 2, d == 2], up
 ]
```

If you want to store the choice in a variable just precede the above with

```
variable = Which[ ... ]
```

Last but not least:

```
 RandomChoice[{up}]]
```

is redundant.

In case you want to implement a kind of random walk with this, have a look here: http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/TurtleGraphics/

Comment: My objective is no random walk until it find a certain value. There will be two different tables, one representing what is known by the subject and another representing the world.
When the subject walk it has to update the table containing what is known by him and in case it find a wall (the number two) it should update and return to previous position.

Answer (score 2):

how about something like this:

```
  choices=Flatten@{If[ matrix[[i+1,j]]!=2 , up ,{}],
           If[ matrix[[i-1,j]]!=2 , down ,{}],
           If[ matrix[[i,j-1]]!=2 , left ,{}],
           If[ matrix[[i,j+1]]!=2 , right ,{}]}
  If[choices!={},RandomChoice[choices]]
```

or even

```
  choices=Flatten@MapThread[If[ #1!=2,#2,{} ]&,
      {{matrix[[i+1,j]],matrix[[i-1,j]],matrix[[i,j-1]],matrix[[i,j+1]]},
        {up,             down,            left,           right}}]
  If[choices!={},RandomChoice[choices]]
```

note in this case the first approach is probably better since your next problem will be throwing errors when you hit the edge so you should do:

```
   If[ i>1 && matrix[[i-1,j]]!=2 , down ,{}]
```

etc.

Comment: pure intuition tells me that your approach would give another result than the definition of the OP. You should, therefore, run it over a short example matrix and compare.

Comment: the only issue is I failed to check the case of no choices, will fix.